# finding out combinations of variables

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

i am trying to encode an multiple ma based strategy and one of my exit condition is that any 3 of the ema's that i use turns to opposite direction.

i am using ema9,20,50 zlsma and McGinnelly. i have determined the slope of the curves to determine their directions with +ve value in uptrend and -ve value in downtrend .
what i want to check is all the possible 10 combinations (5C3)and if any of the same is to the opposite side of the trend to exit

eg: long exit
if (ema9 and 20 and 50)<0 or (9,50,zlsma)<0 or 9,20,zlsma <0 or 9,20,MG<0 or 9,zlsma, MG < 0 ..... to check all the 10 (5c3) combinations and if any of the same is true to exit.

at present i am doing it the hardway

longexit1 = ema9<0 and  ena20<0 and ema50<0
longexit2 = ema9<0 and ema20<0 and zlsma <0
.....

if longexit1 or longexit2 or .....
strategy.exit()

is there any other way around to speedup and simplify

pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `array` and then count the elements in that array using a `for` loop. If the counter will be equal or more then 3, then the condition is met:

```
my_array = array.from(ema9, ema20, ema50, zisma, MG)

long_exit_counter = 0

for ma in my_array
    long_exit_counter := ma > 0 ? long_exit_counter + 1 : long_exit_counter

long_exit = long_exit_counter >= 3
```